# Critical Current Density vs Critical Current

Tags: superconductivity

What is the difference between critical current (Ic) and critical current density (Jc)? How do they relate to one-another?

Answer (score 0):

A current is charge per unit time. A current density is charge per unit time per unit area, where the area is perpendicular to the current. You can integrate a current density over a surface to get the current flowing through the surface.

Comment: Does this work with superconductors (sorry I meant to add that to the question)

Comment: As far as I know, the definitions of current and current density are general and apply to any system,